# Convergence of $S=a(a+b)+a^2(a^2+b^2)+\dots+a^n(a^n+b^n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Check the convergence of $S_n=a(a+b)+a^2(a^2+b^2)+\dots+a^n(a^n+b^n)$ where $|a|,|b|<1$

I am new to convergence. I tried to find $\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n$. If it is a finite number then the series converges otherwise it diverges. Am I correct? Also how do I find the limit. I tried to simplify and removed the parentheses. The I used the formula for a Geometric Series to help me evaluate the limit. But I cannot understand how to evaluate the limit after this.

Comment: What are a and b?

Comment: Compare it with $~\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}~$ that converges for $~|x|<1~$ .

Comment: No hypothesis (for example positivity) on $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=a^2$ and $B=ab$.

$$S_n=a(a+b)+a^2(a^2+b^2)+\dots+a^n(a^n+b^n)$$

can be written :

$$S_n=A+A^2+...+A^n+B+B^2+...+B^n$$

i.e.,

$$S_n=A\dfrac{1-A^n}{1-A}+B\dfrac{1-B^n}{1-B}$$

As $|A|<1$ and $|B|<1$, when $n \to \infty$, $S_n$ converges to :

$$S=A\dfrac{1}{1-A}+B\dfrac{1}{1-B}=a^2\dfrac{1}{1-a^2}+ab\dfrac{1}{1-ab}$$

Comment: Please note that the formulas remain valid even if $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If it converges then $a^{2n}(a^{2n}+b^{2n}) \to 0$ which is possible only when $|a| <1$ and $|ab| <1$.  So these inequalities are necessary for convergence. Conversely, if these inequalities hold then it is clear that $S_n$ converges by comparison with the geometric series $\sum |a|^{2n}$ and $\sum |ab|^{n}$.

Hence a necessary and sufficent condition for existence of $\lim S_n$ is $|a| <1$ and $|ab| <1$.

Also $\lim S_n=\frac {a^{2}} {1-a^{2}}+\frac {ab} {1-ab}$.

Comment: [+1] But I would write more clearly that your first assertion is a necessary condition, that, afterwards , appears as a sufficient condition.

Comment: Subsidiary question : in the case of convergence, is there a closed formula for the sum ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I hope I have made things clear now. As far as sum is concerned all you have t do is add two geometrc sums. Sum the limit can be written down.

Comment: It's OK now. Yes, I just realized that it is the sum of two geometric sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the definition : a serie converges iff the limit of partial sums converges.

but for finding this limit :

1- when you remove parantheses, you have two kind of algebraic formulas : one in terms of "a" and the other one in terms of "a" and "b" (and both are geometric series!)

2- separately, evaluate the limit of these two geometric serie(of course, both are going to be dependant to "a" and "b" respectively!)

3- limit of sum of two sequence is equal to sum of their limits. adding the results of last part will determine convergence of your serie.

Comment: I am sorry but your answer is much too allusive. Moreover the first geometric series depends on $a$ but the second one depends on $a$ **and** $b$. Besides, the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits, but you can have $\infty - \infty$ : what do you in such a case ?

Comment: @jeanMarie oh you are right about part 1! I'll edit that and sorry for not being exact. I tried to give a total sketch because it's not clear what are "a" and "b".

Answer (score 0):

Applying the standard rule for the [sum of a geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) you get:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
S_n
&= a(a+b)+a^2(a^2+b^2)+\dots+a^n(a^n+b^n) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n a^i (a^i + b^i) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{i=1}^n (a^2)^i + \sum_{i=1}^n (ab)^i \\[6pt]
&= a^2 \cdot \frac{1 - (a^2)^{n}}{1-a^2} + ab \cdot \frac{1 - (ab)^{n}}{1-ab} \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Hence, taking $|a|<1$ and $|b|<1$ you have $(a^2)^{n} \rightarrow 0$ and $(ab)^{n} \rightarrow 0$, which gives the limit:

$$S_\infty \equiv \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n
= \frac{a^2}{1-a^2} + \frac{ab}{1-ab}.$$